# Rails .erb file rendering in wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have the following .erb file:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <%= form_for @group, html: { id: 'form' } do |group_form| %>
            <div id="group-members">
            <%= group_form.fields_for :group_members do |group_member_fields| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= group_member_fields.text_field :name , class: 'form-control' %></td>
                    <td><%= group_member_fields.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %></td>
                    <td><%= group_member_fields.check_box :_destroy %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
            </div>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<%= group_form.submit 'Apply', class: "btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" %>
<% end %> <!-- End of form -->
<%= submit_tag 'Add member', type: 'button', class: "btn btn-primary btn-md", id: "add-member-to-group-btn" %>
```

The `div` just below `form_for` with an `id` of `group-members` is being rendered empty and in the wrong position. The elements in `fields_for` are still rendered properly, just not inside of the `group-members div`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `<tr>` elements are allowed as children of a `<tbody>`. You should move your table inside the form. You could then move the attribute `id="group-members"` to a different element such as `<form>`, `<tbody>`, `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, if you want to use `<div>` tag in `<table>`, it must be in `<th>` or `<td>`. For more information, please check the post here:

https://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/